# Print two different things in a single line on a web page

Tags: html, css, angular

If I have to print something like this --

```
Reason :  reason number 1
          reason number 2
          reason number 3

Code :    code number
Remarks : remark
```

So **Reason**, **Code**, and **Remarks** are headings, and thus I have them in  tag, rest of the things such as - reason number 1, reason number 2, code number and remark are the values.

Now, If I use  for the heading, the value automatically goes to a new line, What if I want to print them as key-values in a single line. How can I do so.

Preferably without float.

Comment: Show your json data

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check my stackblitz code here..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xu3foo

Comment: So I will be getting a list of data, the heading is constant, and for every heading there will be a list of data. If it has multiple items I am using li tag, if it has only 1 item I am displaying the content as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwhwpm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<table border="1">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list1;let i = index">
        <tr>
            <td> {{list1[i]}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="list2[i].length > 1">
                <li *ngFor="let li of list2[i]">
                    {{li}}
                </li>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="list2[i].length <= 1">
                {{list2[i]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

.ts

```
  list1 = ["Instructions ", "Reason Code "];
  list2 = [["inst 1 ", "inst 2 "], ["Reason code is so and so"]];
```

Comment: I don't know why I don't like the idea of tables for some reason. Right now I have created different <div> containers and used float on them. The only problem with float is the more we use them the more media-queries we have to use at the end.

Comment: Well, for your preference, you can take the logic and convert it to div

Comment: The existing solution that is there is built using the same idea that you have published. Still, can't thank you enough for prompt replies.